# CherryPy MethodDispatcher with multiple url paths

Tags: python, cherrypy

Does the `MethodDispatcher` from `CherryPy` handle multiple url paths?  I'm trying to do something like below, but while requests to `/customers` work fine, requests to `/orders` always return '404 Nothing matches the given URI'.

```
class Customers(object):
    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        return getCustomers()

class Orders(object):
    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        return getOrders()


class Root(object):
    pass

root = Root()
root.customers = Customers()
root.orders = Orders()

conf = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
        'server.socket_port': 8000,
    },
    '/': {
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
    },
}

cherrypy.quickstart(root, '/', conf)
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? I ran into exactly same problem...

Comment: I suspect it was a bug in the version of CherryPy that I was using.  I couldn't reproduce it on a different machine so I cleaned my environment, reinstalled everything and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it, try using:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(Root())

cherrypy.tree.mount(Customers(), '/customers',
    {'/':
        {'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}
    }
)
cherrypy.tree.mount(Orders(), '/orders',
    {'/':
        {'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}
    }
)

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

It seems like in order to expose methods in `Root` class you have to use annotation `@cherrypy.expose`. Setting `exposed = True` probably won't work.

See my answer to my own question [Combining REST dispatcher with the default one in a single CherryPy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536057/combining-rest-dispatcher-with-the-default-one-in-a-single-cherrypy-app/22475983#22475983).