# Combining REST dispatcher with the default one in a single CherryPy app

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to make CherryPy to handle request to `/api` via `cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()` and all other request (like `/`) to some default dispatcher.

After reading CherryPy's doc I have no idea how to do this. They use both routing methods only separately but this is such a basic thing that I believe it has to work together.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import cherrypy


class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello world'

class RestAPI(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def POST(self, blah):
        return 'ok'

cherrypy.config.update({
    'global': {
        'environment': 'production',
        'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port': 8080,
    }
})


root = Root()
root.api = RestAPI()

conf = {
    '/api': {
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()
    }
}

cherrypy.quickstart(root, '', config=conf)
```

By calling `curl 'http://localhost:8080/'` it gives me `Hello world` which is correct.
But calling `curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/api'` returns just 404.

By the way, the're eaxctly the same question without any answer [CherryPy MethodDispatcher with multiple url paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081265/cherrypy-methoddispatcher-with-multiple-url-paths).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The weird thing was that I had to expose `index` method (and all other methods in `Root` class) using annotation `@cherrypy.expose` and not just by setting `exposed = True` like in `RestAPI` class. I don't know why.

To properly test POST handler I didn't have to pass any variables but still I had to set `Content-length: 0` header.

```
class Root(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello world'


class RestAPI(object):

    exposed = True

    def POST(self):
        return 'post'

    def GET(self):
        return 'get'


cherrypy.config.update({
    'global': {
        'environment': 'test_suite',
        'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port': 8080,
    }
})

cherrypy.tree.mount(Root())

cherrypy.tree.mount(RestAPI(), '/api',
    {'/':
        {'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}
    }
)

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Proper way to test POST using cURL:

`curl -X POST --header "Content-length: 0" http://localhost:8080/api`

Comment: The real fix was that you moved the "request.dispatch" config to the root config. You can't specify a different dispatcher at a sub-path because the config is still being gathered while dispatching--chicken and egg. You have to specify dispatchers only at '/' or 'global'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late, perhaps you already found the error. Your class `RestApi` must be exposed. That decorator doesn't work with `MethodDispatcher`.